# Why can't my dynamically allocated array be accessed outside of it's function? [C]

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to access an `array` that was created in function `fooA()` in the `main` function. I'm dynamically allocating the `array` using `malloc` and pointing a passed pointer at it, but in main the pointer no longer points to the same value.

```
int main() {
    int *test;
    fooA(test);
    printf("%d\n", test[0]);
    free(test);
}

void fooA(int *pass){
    int pass = malloc(5*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        pass[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is because function arguments are value passed. So after the function call, the value of test is the same before the function call

Comment: Does this even compile? You define a variable `int pass` inside a function that has paramter `int *pass`. IMHO both variables are in same scope and have different type. In best case you are hiding your parameter anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the problems in code....

```cpp
void fooA(int *pass)  /*<<<<  pass is declared here */
{
    /* 
       however you have redefined pass as a different type here.
       This variable hides the previous definition of pass. 
       I'd suggest turning up the warning level on your compiler 
       to catch errors like this. (-Wall on gcc/clang, or warning 
       level 4 on Visual C)
     */
    int pass = malloc(5*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        pass[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Later when you call the method, you are passing a ***copy*** of test into fooA, rather than a *reference* to the original variable. i.e. Any changes you make to 'pass' within fooA will be working on the copy, and not the original variable.

```cpp
    int *test;
    fooA(test);
```

The easiest option here would be to simply return the pointer.

```cpp
/* change the prototype to return the pointer instead of passing in as arg! */
int* fooA(void);

int main() {

    /* this should now be good */
    int *test = fooA();
    printf("%d\n", test[0]);
    free(test);
}

int* fooA(void){
    int* pass = malloc(5*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        pass[i] = i;
    }
    return pass;
}
```

If you wanted to do it with a function argument, it's possible, but only if you use a pointer to a pointer, i.e.

```
void fooA(int** pass);

int main() {
    int *test;
    fooA(&test); /*< passing address of test variable */
    printf("%d\n", test[0]);
    free(test);
}

void fooA(int** pass) {
    /* need to dereference pass here to modify the original pointer value */
    *pass = malloc(5*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        (*pass)[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Although this question is tagged as C, for completeness, in C++ you can pass the variable by reference *(i.e. add the & symbol to the end of the type)*

```cpp
void fooA(int*& pass) {
    // working on the original variable, rather than a copy. 
    pass = (int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        pass[i] = i;
    }
}
```

And now this code would work just fine:

```cpp
    int *test;
    fooA(test);
```

Comment: It should be `int* fooA(void);` (otherwise it's a non-prototype declaration)